order in line n balls from n same black balls and n distinct white balls numbered from 1 to n
I'm trying to figure out how many ways there are to order $n$  balls in a line when I have $n$ identical black balls and $n$ distinct white balls numbered from 1 to  $n$, where the order matters.
Here's my attempt:

Let $k$ be the number of black balls.
Choose $n - k$ white balls from the $n$ distinct white balls. This can be done in ${n\choose n-k}$ =
The total number of ways to arrange these $n$  balls in a line is $n!$.
Since the $k$ black balls are identical, we need to divide by the number of permutations of these $k$  black balls, which is $k!$.

So, the total number of ways should be:

$ \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{n!}{k!} $

Can someone please confirm if this approach is correct, or let me know if there's a mistake in my reasoning? Thank you!

Your formula is  correct, the only suggestion I have is that it might be better if you gave primacy to the distinct white balls in the formula.
If $k$ white balls are to be chosen, the # of arrangements is  ${\binom{n}{k}}^2 k!$ for choosing the balls and arranging them in the line.
so # of possible arrangements = $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\;\; {\binom{n}{k}}^2 k!$
This way of calculation we are only considering white balls, the vacant spaces automatically get filled by black balls, and we could simplify the expression further by  using the falling factorial $n^\underline{k}$
(which, if you haven't been exposed to it yet, simply means $n(n-1)(n-2)...$ to $k$ terms) to get
# of possible arrangements $=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\;\; \binom{n}{k} n^\underline k$
